# Using guizero and a text datafile to create GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, guizero

So I'm trying to help a student figure out how to create a simple quiz by reading from a text file with the questions, options, and answers. He wants to use guizero instead of the simple built-in input() and print() functions.

I would like him to avoid creating a separate check function for each question, but I don't have much experience with guizero. I've been reading the manual pages, and the below code approximates what we are trying to accomplish but doesn't work because `selected_value` is not defined until after the program runs. Am I approaching this the wrong way?

```
from guizero import App, Text, ButtonGroup

app = App(title="Quiz Test", height=800, width=600)

def check_answer(selected_value, answer):
    if selected_value == answer:
        result.value = "Correct"
    else:
        result.value = "Wrong"

question_data = []
data_file = open("quiz_ques.txt", 'r')

for line in data_file.read().splitlines():
    question_data = line.split(", ")

    question_data.reverse() ; question = question_data.pop()
    question_data.reverse() ; answer = question_data.pop()

    q_options = question_data
    
    text = Text(app, text=question)
    choice = ButtonGroup(app, options=q_options, selected=1, command=check_answer, args=[selected_value, answer])
    result = Text(app)

data_file.close()
app.display()
```

Answer (score 1):

try changing

`command=check_answer()`

to

`command=check_answer`

in the original version you were calling `check_answer()` as soon as you defined your program... in the second version it will not be called until the button is clicked

Comment: Yeah, that doesn't quite work either, unfortunately.



    combo = Combo(app, options=q_options, command=check_answer, args=selected_value, answer)

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out using a couple of lists for anyone looking for a solution. Someone who is more of a python expert could probably simplify this, using some pythonic idiom, built-in functions, or standard modules, but this solution works even if it's a bit of a hack. Improvements on this are welcomed. :)

```
from guizero import App, Text, ButtonGroup

app = App(title="Quiz Test", height=800, width=600) 

def check_answer(answer, result, cnt):
    if choices[cnt].value == answer:
        result.text_color = 'green'
        result.value = "Correct"
        update_score()

    else:
        result.text_color = 'red'
        result.value = "Wrong"
        update_score()


def update_score():
    score = 0
    for result in results:
        if result.value == "Correct":
            score += 1 
    score_txt.value = "Score: " + str(score)

question_data = []
data_file = open("quiz_ques.txt", 'r')

cnt = 0 
results = []
choices = []

for line in data_file.read().splitlines():
    question_data = line.split(", ")

    question_data.reverse() ; question = question_data.pop()
    question_data.reverse() ; answer = question_data.pop()

    q_options = question_data
    
    question = Text(app, text=question)
    question.text_color = 'white'

    results.append(Text(app))
    choices.append(ButtonGroup(app, options=q_options, command=check_answer, args=[answer, results[cnt], cnt]))
    cnt += 1 

score_txt = Text(app, color='white', size=40)

data_file.close()
app.display()
```